# What happened to the clock indicator?

Tags: 11.10, unity, indicator

I'm not sure when it happened, but on my 11.10 desktop system, the clock indicator no longer appears.  Where has the lost time gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that when I removed `evolution*`, it took the indicator with it.

When I went to install `indicator-datetime`, I saw that it requires some baggage:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common indicator-datetime
  libedataserverui-3.0-1
```

Comment: evolution-data-server, IIRC, is now used by much more than Evolution. When removing Evolution, leave evolution-data-server*.

Comment: @JCCyC  Oof.  Yeah, I was being overly optimistic that more dependencies had been removed.